# Take a continuous map from a product topology, and fix one of the 2 arguments. Is the resultant map continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, topological-vector-spaces

Let $A,B$ and $C$ be topological spaces. Suppose we have a continuous map from the product space
$$f: A\times B \to C$$
Let $a\in A$, and consider the function
$$g_a : B \to C \\
g_a(b) := f(a,b)$$
(Aside - is there a standard name for $g_a$, like a 'section' or something?

Given $f$ is continuous, is $g_a$ also continuous? Is this true for general topologies on $A$, or are some separation conditions required?

Comment: Composition of continuous maps is continuous. This is composing $f$ with the inclusion $\{ a \} \times B \to A \times B$, so it suffices to check that this map is continuous. The inclusion $\{ a \} \to A$ is continuous (constant maps are always continuous), and the product $f \times g : X_1 \times X_2 \to Y_1 \times Y_2$ of two continuous maps $f : X_1 \to Y_1, g : X_2 \to Y_2$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, because if you define $i:\{a\}×B\hookrightarrow A×B$, then $i$ is continuous*.   Now let $h:B\to\{a\}×B$ be the obvious homeomorphism.  Then $g_a=f\circ i\circ h$ is then a composition of continuous maps.

*$i$ is called the inclusion of $\{a\}×B$ into $A×B$.  And it's continuous if you put the subspace topology on $\{a\}×B$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is continuous: $g_a=f\circ i_a$ where $i_a:B\to A\times B$ takes $b$
to $(a,b)$. The map $i_a$ is continuous (the inverse image of
a standard basis element of $A\times B$ is open in $B$) and therefore so is $g_a$,
since composites of continuous maps are continuous.

Comment: Another way to see that $i_a$ is continuous is by using the universal property for the product topology: $\pi_A \circ i_a$ is a constant map (so always continuous) and $\pi_B \circ i_a$ is the identity on $B$ which is also continuous. So $i_a$ is continuous and so $g_$ too.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Of course, that's the best way to prove it, but maybe not so appealing for beginners.

Comment: The fact that a map into a product is continuous iff all its compositions with projections are, is very commonly taught in text books.